# Identify all the Oracle Processes between two snap IDs

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-administration

Need your help with an issue with which I have struggled for two days so far.
I had a problem on my Database which was the result of an "***ORA-00020: maximum number of processes exceeded***".

I have done the following so far:

I have identified the SNAP_IDs for the timeframe when the problem occurred:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_hist_snapshot
WHERE begin_interval_time >= TO_DATE('27.11.20 07:30:00', 'DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SS')
AND end_interval_time <= TO_DATE('27.11.20 10:30:18', 'DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Afterwards, I used the known SNAP_IDs to see if the value for CURRENT_UTILIZATION and the value MAX_UTILIZATION was ok or was it indeed exceeded. The following SELECT confirmed that the value for the process has been exceeded.

```
SELECT d.snap_id, d.resource_name, a.begin_interval_time, a.end_interval_time, d.current_utilization, 
       d.max_utilization, d.initial_allocation, d.limit_value, a.startup_time
FROM dba_hist_resource_limit d
JOIN dba_hist_snapshot a 
ON a.snap_id = d.snap_id
WHERE d.resource_name = 'processes'
AND d.snap_id BETWEEN 14536 AND 14538
ORDER BY d.snap_id ASC;
```

Trying to identify what caused my problem, I eventually reached the DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_SUMMARY Table which helped me out only with a confirmation that the process value has been exceeded.

```
SELECT snap_id, begin_time, end_time, metric_name, maxval
FROM dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
WHERE snap_id BETWEEN 14536 AND 14538
AND metric_id = 2118;
```

What I am trying to identify is what caused this increased number of processes. Unfortunately, as the problem occurred on 27.11, the information from within V$process is no longer relevant for me.

Is there any possibility to identify what "caused" all those processes, maybe using a HIST table which is not known to me? Or is it another way to retrieve the desired information?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am working on an Oracle 12.1 DB.

Comment: Check the alert log for related messages, and see if that directs you to any trace files from the time of the error. If the excess  processes were caused by user sessions then you might see in the listener log a spike in connection requests with relevant information about the clients. Otherwise, your best bet would be a real-time monitoring tool that would keep a detailed, down to the second history of everything going on in your database. Perhaps EM Database Express? OS-level logs and monitoring might also be a help here, if you have anything available that can keep a history of processes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only had access to the listener logs. There i was able to identify that within almost 20 mins a single server created 5000 connections to the Database. I assume that this is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: It's certainly a good place to start looking, especially if you're sure this is abnormal behavior. That many new dedicated server sessions would potentially cause a lot of churn on your DB server, even if they only lasted a fraction of a second each. If you are auditing logins then you could also check the DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL or UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL views to see how long each of those sessions lasted, and which user account was being churned.